# Performing ridge regression with multiple outputs in MATLAB

Tags: regression, matlab

Is there any way to do ridge regression in MATLAB with multiple outputs. I mean the ridge function by default just supports one output?

Comment: Yes. The ridge function by default supports a vector $y$ and not a matrix $Y$. That being said you can always reshape your matrix in a vector, use Kronecker products in to reformulate your $X$ matrix into $X_{big} = I_p \otimes X$ and take it from there. (Pay attention to the error structure you are assuming in this case though; $p$ is the number of your multiple outputs.)

Answer (score 1):

Just perform each one separately. There is no benefit from doing it at once, except maybe some decrease in run time.

Comment: +1 because of the hands-on point-of-view. But, you can't hide from the fact that this approach enforces a diagonal error structure $\Sigma_E$, ie. if $E \sim N(0,\Sigma_E$), then $\Sigma_E \sim D_E$. Yes, in the case of OLS that would come around OK but of the top of my head I can't remember any results for ridge regression. Check Izenman 2008, Chapt. 6.2 for more details.

Comment: True, the output covariance is diagonal in that case.

Answer (score 0):

There are different approach to performa multi-output regression. Check for ERC or SST approches. You can't perform directly a multi-output regression with ridge so you have to be tricky to do it and take in consideration the potential correlation there are between your targets.